# Passing multiple variables to a view?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, variables, view

so,i have two variables `$posts` and `$comments` that holds the array of posts and comments respectively,i have a separate view that accepts these variables,executes a foreach loop and prints them on the same page. The question here is,how do i pass both the variables to a view?

If its a single variable i pass it like this `$this->load->view('myview',$myvar)`.

I tried passing it as an array like this,but still it doesnt work.

```
$data=array($var1,$var2);
$this->load->view('myview',$data);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: How do you use the passed arguments inside the view?

Comment: say,i have this variable $comments['cmt'] to be passed,once its passed in my view,it does a foreach on cmt and prints the output individually. like this,

    `foreach($cmt as $comment)`
    `echo $comment->content;` 
hope thats clear.

Comment: @arvid: You should merge/union the variables you'd like to pass instead making an array of it's own out of it. in your example, `$var1` will become `${0}` in your view and `$var2` will become `${1}`. If `$var1` is `$comments` from your last comment, that would be `foreach(${0} as $comment)` but just do `$data = $var1 + $var2` instead. See my answer. You then could access them as usual.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to access the variable in your view as you pass it. Using `array($var1,$var2);` is valid but probably not what you wanted to achieve.

Try

```
$data = $var1 + $var2;
```

or

```
$data = array_merge($var1, $var2);
```

instead. See **[Views](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)** for detailed documentation how to access variables passed to a view.

The problem with using `array($var1,$var2);` is that you will create two view variables: `${0}` and `${1}` (the array's keys become the variable names, you have two keys in your array: `0` and `1`).

Those variable names are *invalid labels* so you need to enclose the name with `{}` on the view level.

By that you loose the ability to name the variables usefully.

Comment: thank you so much. this seems to pass the variables as it should. :)

Comment: How will you be able to loop posts and comments separately with such implementation?

Comment: @Gedrox: By their variable name, so probably don't get your question.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do in your controller:

```
$data['posts'] = $posts;
$data['comments'] = $comments;
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

Then, in your view you just simply do something like:

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
...
}
```

You can hold any object in the $data variable that you pass to your view. When I need to traverse through result sets that I get from my models I do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Using associative array looks the best possible solution.
take an array

```
$data = array(
    'posts' => $posts,
    'comments' => $comments,
);
$this->load->view('myview',$data);
```

Probably this will help you to get a solution.

Comment: Edited your question a bit so it's clear to what it refers to, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

this is another and recommended way using [compact](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.compact.php):

```
$data1 = 'your data';
$data2 = 123;
$data3 = array();

$this->load->view('myview', compact('data1', 'data2', 'data3');
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $data1 = 'your data';
$data2 = 123;
$data3 = array();

$this->load->view('myview', $data1 + $data2 + $data3);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score -2):

```
$this->render($views_array,$data);
```